# PHPUnit fatal error call to undefined method on mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I want to test that a method on an object is called. I want to do this by making a mock of `Object`, rather than any specific class. But the following code throws a fatal error:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testSomeMethodIsCalled()
    {
        $mock = $this->getMock('Object');
        $mock->expects($this->once())
                ->method('someMethod');
        $mock->someMethod();
    }
}
```

The above dies with an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mock_Object_204ac105::someMethod()
```

I'm sure there was a way to do this, without having to write a class that actually has a `someMethod()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set array of methods that should be available in mock when you create it via `$this->getMock()`, so this code should work:

```
$mock = $this->getMock('Object', ['someMethod']);
```